# How to create an xorg.conf in Ubuntu 16.04 to prevent 4K resolution being used

Tags: xorg, display-resolution

I have an Ubuntu machine that I use as a dedicated Kodi device. It has built in Intel Graphics.

I recently bought a new 4K TV which is great except I pass the HDMI signal through an AV receiver that cannot cope with a 4K signal. If I change the resolution in Ubuntu to 1920x1080 (which is all I need for Kodi) it has a nasty habit of reverting to 4K on reboots and if the TV is switched off and on again.

I have tried a few xrandr scripts on startup but nothing has been 100% reliable in preventing the switch to 4K. Reading around it sounds like an xorg.conf file would be the best way to manage this situation but I have struggled to generate one.

If I go to a console screen <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> and shut down unity

```
sudo service stop lightdm
```

I am not able to then generate an `xorg.conf` file. If I run `sudo X -configure` I get the following;

```
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-59-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux kodi 4.8.0-36-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sun Feb 5 09:39:57 UTC 2017 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic root=UUID=2285a6a6-3668-451f-a779-9451f3880ce7 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 26 January 2017  12:26:18AM
xorg-server 2:1.18.4-1ubuntu6.1~16.04.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Mar 27 22:54:03 2017
List of video drivers:
    amdgpu
    ati
    intel
    nouveau
    qxl
    vmware
    fbdev
    vesa
    modesetting
    radeon
No devices to configure.  Configuration failed.
(EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.
```

I'm stuck at this point before even trying to wrangle the `xorg.conf` file into shape to get what I want done. Any helpful clues as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you just copy the _~/.config/monitors.xml_ file to the _/etc/xdg/gnome-settings-daemon/xrandr/_ directory, after having configured the display to be 1920x1080 in the user's logged in session, it will work after a reboot. However, I'm having trouble finding the details on how I once arrived at such a conclusion with a previous monitor setup of my own.